# Access nth duplicate field in Json file Python

Tags: python, json

I have this json data I need to iterate through. The general format of the json data is

```
{
 "Name" : "Bob"
 "value" : "1100"
 "morestuff" : "otherstuff"
 "otherTermResults" : {

   "stuff" : "morestuff"
   "things" : "thisandthat" 
   "value" : "1200"
   }
 "value" : "1300"
 ....
 ....
 ....
} // end
```

As you can see there are 3 fields named "value". In python i can access the first 2 with

```
  line_object = json.loads(line)
  value1 = line_object["value"] //gets me 1000
  value2 = line_object["otherTermResults"][0]["value"] // gets me 1200
```

This reliable gets me the first 2 "value" fields. I dont know how to get the 3rd "value" the one reading 1300. In addition the json data im working with may have an "n" unknown duplicates of "value" not nested in a subfield just for one name, in this case "bob". I read a few things saying you have to access the correct index but that was for jquery. In python

```
json.loads(line)
```

only loads in the first field that matches the "value". how do i resolve this issue in python? Do i need to switch to another language?

Answer (score 0):

json.loads takes an object_pairs_hook that you can use to customize behavior.  For example, to collect the duplicate values into a list you might do something like:

```
import json

def find_value(ordered_pairs):
    d = {}
    for k, v in ordered_pairs:
        if k == "value":
           d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        else:
           d[k] = v
    return d

json.loads(raw_post_data, object_pairs_hook=find_value)
```

Comment: what is ordered_pairs in this context?

Comment: "object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs." https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/json.html.  So, it will be called with an ordered list of key, value pairs for each key, value in the JSON object literal.